# Проверка QLineEdit на заданный текст и после нажатия pushButton совершается действие

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Помогите сделать проверку на введенную в `lineEdit` строку, после чего при нажатии на `pushButton` открывалась бы некая ссылка.

```
def si():
    if ??? == "123":
        webbrowser.open('link', new=2)

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(si)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def si():
    if ui.lineEdit.text() == "123": # здесь lineEdit - имя, которое вы дали объекту
        webbrowser.open('link', new=2)

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(si)
```

Comment: имя у лайнэдита не менял. lineEdit и есть. после нажатия на pushButton ничего не происходит, а в командной строке выдает Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in si
    if self.lineEdit.text() == "123":
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: первый раз на данном форуме, поэтому может будет удобнее обменяться какой-то соц. сетью и если вас не затруднит, я объясню более подробно и дам больше кода. весь гугл перерыл уже если честно)

Comment: я кое что просмотрел, попробуйте новый вариант

Comment: вау. теперь все работает. я целый разные варианты пробовал :D и такой тоже, но без () после text. спасибо :)

Comment: еще, если не сложно. как сделать, чтобы ссылка открывалась при условии, что выполняется эта функция и еще одна, а не по отдельности? то есть и первая и ui.lineEdit_2.text() == "321"

Comment: лучше задайте новый вопрос, из комментариев сложно понять что либо